# Expanding the Fourier Series with odd extension

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, pi

My question wants me to derive the equality 
  /4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7... using the Fourier Series:

```
4/ ∑ 1/(2n+1)sin((2n+1)x) = -1 if -1 < x < 0
                               1 if  0 < x < 1
```

To me it looks like the Fourier Sine expansion of f(x) = 1 with an odd extension, but where does the sin(nx) disappear to?

Comment: Did you mean $\sin(2nx)$, as the odd numbered are present in the formula. Consider the symmetry around $x=1/2$ to explain those zero coefficients.

Comment: I know that if x=1/2 then the series works, but how would I go about including that in my derivation of the equality?

Comment: Because $\sin(2n\pi x)$ is odd around $x=1/2$, the corresponding integral and thus coefficient is zero.